# Canonical symplectic form on cotangent bundle of complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Given any smooth manifold $M$, its cotangent bundle $T^*M$ is a symplectic manifold, with the canonical [symplectic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_one-form).

If $M$ is a complex manifold then $T^*M$ is also a  [complex manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_vector_bundle).

Thus, $T^*M$ is a complex symplectic manifold.

Does it follow that the canonical symplectic form is holomorphic?

If not, what condition can be placed on $M$ so that it is? For example [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46752/is-the-cotangent-bundle-to-a-kahler-manifold-hyperkahler) on Overflow says that if $M$ is Kahler then the symplectic form is holomorphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One should not expect such a thing.

On the one hand, the symplectic form on $T^*M$ is canonically constructible for any smooth manifold $M$, regardless of any more structure on $M$. On the other hand, no canonical complex structure exists on $T^*M$ without some specific structure on $M$ (such as a Riemannian metric or a complex structure). The specification of any such structure has *a priori* no reason to lead to a complex structure on $T^*M$ which is naturally related to the canonical symplectic structure on $T^*M$ since the latter does not depend on the specified structure on $M$.

Even when $M$ is Kahler, the induced symplectic (in fact, Kahler) form on $T^*M$ has *a priori* no reason to coincide with the canonical symplectic form. In fact, I doubt that they coincide in general.

---

To be more specific, note that if you put coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^m)$ on $M$, you induce Darboux coordinates $(x^1, p_1, \dots, x^m, p_m)$ on $T^*M$. Incidentally, to speak loosely, the symplectic structure intertwines 'base' vectors (*i.e.* $\partial /\partial x^k$) with 'fiber' vectors (*i.e.* $\partial/ \partial p_k$).

If you put holomorphic coordinates $(x^1+iy^1, \dots, x^m+iy^m)$ on a complex manifold $M$, you induce holomorphic coordinates $(x^1+iy^1, p_m+iq_m, \dots, x^m+iy^m, p_m + iq_m)$ on $T^*M$. Incidentally, to speak loosely, the complex structure intertwines real 'base' vectors (*i.e.* $\partial/\partial x^k$) with other ones (*i.e.* $\partial/\partial y^k$) and real 'fiber' vectors (*i.e.* $\partial/\partial p_k$) with other ones (*i.e.* $\partial/\partial q_k$).

However, if the symplectic form were to be holomorphic with respect to the complex structure, it should be expressible (at least to first order in the coordinates) as

$$i/2 \sum_{k=1}^m \left( d(x^k + iy^k) \wedge d(x^k - i y^k) + d(p_k + i q_k) \wedge d(p_k - i q_k) \right) = \sum_{k=1}^m (dx^k \wedge dy^k + dp_k \wedge dq_k)$$

which suggests that the symplectic form would intertwine 'base' vectors with other ones and 'fiber' vectors with other ones. This is not the case of the canonical symplectic form.

---

All these considerations can be explicitly checked in the simplest case when $M = \mathbb{C}$ equipped with its standard Kahler structure, as they are then precise. $M$ is Lagrangian when seen as the zero section of $T^*M$ with its canonical symplectic form, but it is a symplectic subspace of $T^*M \simeq (\mathbb{C}^2, i)$ with its induced Kahler structure. But when an almost complex structure is compatible with a symplectic form, any complex subspace is then symplectic, which shows that the canonical symplectic structure on $T^*M$ is not compatible with the induced complex structure from $M$.